# Empty attributes in JSX Expression is no longer assignable to "props" type of void

Tags: typescript

I have following declaration for my React component which used to compile in TypeScript 2.2, but now it is an error in TypeScript 2.3

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<void, {}> {
  render() {
    return <div> Hello </div>
  }
}

// TS 2.3 : error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 
// 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<MyComponent> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>...'.
//     Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'void'.
let m = <MyComponent />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `void`, the type parameter should be `{}`.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
  render() {
    return <div> Hello </div>
  }
}
```

In TypeScript 2.3, empty attributes are treated as empty object literals, which is exactly how React behaves for empty `props`. TypeScript 2.3 now behaves this way too, so when there are no attributes, it gives an empty object literal type.